# Unable to save many fields using django modelforms in django shell

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to save using modelforms in django shells.The model is having a manytomany field in it. I have created to dict as follows(in the django shell):

```
dict = {'title':'TestBlog4','slug':'test4','published':1,'sites':'example.com'}
```

Here sites is a manytomany field

Then I create a form:

```
blog = BlogForm(dict)
```

but when I check blog.is_valid(), it gives me false.Then when I list the errors using blog.errors.It gives the following error:

```
{'sites': [u'Enter a list of values.']}
```

I would be very grateful, if you can help reslove this errors or point me to some place where this error is solved

Thanks

Comment: Without showing the model and form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QueryDict.

```
from django.http import QueryDict
from urllib import urlencode
data = QueryDict(urlencode({...your_dict...}))
```

Comment: i tried to save it through the instance of the form class, but the manytomany field is not getting saved

Comment: I tried to mix this with the method suggested by msamoylov but the problem persists

Comment: please attach your model and modelform

Answer (score 0):

Sites should be a list of the primary keys of the related sites, instead of the domain name.

Try the following:

```
example_site=Site.objects.get(domain_name="example.com")
dict = {'title':'TestBlog4','slug':'test4','published':1,'sites':[example_site.id,]}
```

Comment: This method worked fine and the form validated and data got saved too.But when I goto the admin UI and click on "change" for blog, it gives me error "Nonetype is not iterable".

Comment: It's very difficult to help you unless you update your question to include your models, form and full traceback.